# Understanding Selector nth

Tags: css-selectors, automated-tests, selector, e2e-testing, testcafe

I use TestCafe Studio to record some tests. But these tests are useful if you will change the structure of some lists. I try to optimize the Selectors a little bit in Java Script to have a test that will run in some lists independently. But for this, I need to understand also the "nth" element of the Selector.

In my case the TestCafe Studio script contain:

```
.click(Selector('div').withText('testcafe#1').nth(9).find('div').nth(2).find('div').nth(1))
```

[image: Tree from devtools]

Please take a look at the page tree. I do not understand what "nth(9)" element means. What is the ancestor here form "withText"? Means from what element in a tree I have to count 9 forward?

I have the big problem that "nth" looks like always a dynamic number. Special in React webpages. So it is really not useable until I know where the parent is from what it counts. 
On the webpage, I have to test a list element is sometimes nth(36) and sometimes nth(37). So anybody can help me out where TestCafe starts to count nth?

Answer (score 4):

> I do not understand what "nth(9)" element means.

The [TestCafe documentation help topic](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#nth) says: 'Finds an element by its index in the matching set.'.
I.e. TestCafe takes the result of the chain and gets the necessary element by index.
 
To calculate the target element for the `Selector('div').withText('testcafe#1').nth(9)` selector, TestCafe will perform the following steps:

- find all `div` elements
- filter only these elements whose `innerText` property contains the 'testcafe#1' value
- take the 9th element from the result of previous step

> I have the big problem that "nth" looks like always a dynamic number.

You are right. It's not correct to use the `nth` method for dynamic lists. Instead, try to use another selector based on a class name, tag name or something else.